# How do you get Django to make a RESTful call?

Tags: django, http, rest

Note: I'm not trying to provide a RESTful api, I'm trying to call one.

```
def index( request, *args, **kwargs ):
    context = {}
    context['some_json'] = make_remote_api_call( "http://exampl.com/objects/" )

    return render_to_response( 'index.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

Or is this just ridiculous and I should make the client always do it? Basically, I'm curious as to how to properly divide my website so that different servers (internal protected ones) can provide different subsets of info.

Comment: My opinion is to get the client to make the requests where possible; making your webserver block for an external call isn't very scalable or nice in general. However, be aware that AJAX requests must be made to the same domain (you can't do cross domain AJAX requests without using iframes, jsonp, or other trickery).

Comment: I realize that having the webserver block isn't scalable, but at least in this situation it's really no different than waiting for a database call to return.

Comment: except that the call you make to a remote server can (potentially) trigger multiple database calls and other blocking operations too. To be clear, it sounds like making the server do it is right in your case, but it's good to be aware of the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [requests](http://python-requests.org/) library. [Here is some discussion](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2882301) on it and I did a talk on "Consuming Web APIs with Python" at PyOhio that you might find interesting or helpful

- [Video](http://blip.tv/pyohio/consuming-web-apis-with-python-5439492).
- [Slides](http://issackelly.github.com/Consuming-Web-APIs-with-Python-Talk/slides/slides.html#intro).
- [Code](https://github.com/issackelly/Consuming-Web-APIs-with-Python-Talk).

Comment: Thanks, Requests was exactly what I was looking for. I should have mentioned that I knew about urllib but it didn't seem like the right solution. Thanks! ps - I'm watching your video, so far so good.

Answer (score 3):

“RESTful call” in practice just means making an HTTP request. There are a couple of built-in modules in Python that let you do this:

- [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)
- [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)

Then there are 3rd-party modules, like the one [mentioned by @Issac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699796/how-do-you-get-django-to-make-a-restful-call/7700269#7700269) (which, based on my very limited experience with urllib2 and httplib, looks much better than them for your purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Slumber is a RESTful data connector that can be used to make proper RESTful data services from Django systems.

https://github.com/KayEss/django-slumber