# Python Piston equivalent for consuming RESTful APIs?

Tags: python, django, django-piston

Is there something equivalent of Django [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) but for **consuming** RESTful API's?

Comment: Maybe [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) in conjunction with JSON?

Comment: I asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699796/how-do-you-get-django-to-make-a-restful-call

Use the Requests package.

Comment: Are you sure you mean **consume**? Looks like Piston allows you to create RESTful API?

Comment: Piston allows me to create them, but I want to consume other parties's APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of REST is that you don't NEED a special client to interact with the API...just anything that can communicate via HTTP.

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) is the current hotness in Python HTTP Libraries.
[HTTPLib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) is also very robust

The challenge with REST is that while the verbs are standard (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), the nouns are completely arbitrary, left to the whims of whoever wrote the URL structure. I guess that's why authors often create a wrapper/language-specific implementation of the RESTFul API (eg [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries)).