# Django: check if an image exists at some particular url

Tags: python, django, image, file

Just wondering is there any way I can check whether the url links to a valid image or not in Django.

Comment: If the image is on the same machine as Django, then you can simply read the file and validate it. If not, then you have to make a REST call and parse the result.

Comment: Image doesn't exist on the same machine as Django.Actually I have a form where user needs to submit a url of some image.I just want to check if that url links to any actual image or not.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699796/how-do-you-get-django-to-make-a-restful-call (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a failsafe method.
First, parse the url to get the domain and the rest.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://example.com/random/folder/path.html'
>>> parse_object = urlparse(url)
>>> parse_object.netloc
'example.com'
>>> parse_object.path
'/random/folder/path.html'
>>> parse_object.scheme
'http'
```

Now, use the above information to get the content type. Use the `parse_object.netloc` instead of sstatic.net, and the `parse_object.path` instead of the hardcoded path.

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("sstatic.net")
>>> conn.request("HEAD", "/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.getheaders()
[('content-length', '1150'), ('x-powered-by', 'ASP.NET'), ('accept-ranges', 'bytes'),         ('last-modified', 'Mon, 02 Aug 2010 06:04:04 GMT'), ('etag', '"2187d82832cb1:0"'), ('cache-control', 'max-age=604800'), ('date', 'Sun, 12 Sep 2010 13:39:26 GMT'), ('content-type', 'image/x-icon')]
```

This tells you it's an image (image/* mime-type) of 1150 bytes. Enough information for you to decide if you want to fetch the full resource.

**EDIT**

For shortened urls, like `http://goo.gl/IwruD` which points to `http://ubuntu.icafebusiness.com/images/ubuntugui2.jpg`, in the response that you get, there's an additional parameter called `'location'`.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("goo.gl")
>>> conn.request("HEAD", "/IwruD")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.getheaders()
[('x-xss-protection', '1; mode=block'),
 ('x-content-type-options', 'nosniff'),
 ('transfer-encoding', 'chunked'),
 ('age', '64'),
 ('expires', 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'),
 ('server', 'GSE'),
 ('location', 'http://ubuntu.icafebusiness.com/images/ubuntugui2.jpg'),
 ('pragma', 'no-cache'),
 ('cache-control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate'),
 ('date', 'Sat, 30 Jun 2012 08:52:15 GMT'),
 ('x-frame-options', 'SAMEORIGIN'),
 ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')]
```

While in the direct url, you wouldn't find it.

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("ubuntu.icafebusiness.com")
>>> conn.request("HEAD", "/images/ubuntugui2.jpg")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.getheaders()
[('content-length', '78603'), ('accept-ranges', 'bytes'), ('server', 'Apache'), ('last-modified', 'Sat, 16 Aug 2008 01:36:17 GMT'), ('etag', '"1fb8277-1330b-45489c3ad2640"'), ('date', 'Sat, 30 Jun 2012 08:55:46 GMT'), ('content-type', 'image/jpeg')]
```

You can look for that using a simple code:

```
>>> r = res.getheaders()
>>> redirected = False
>>> for e in r:
>>>     if(e[0] == 'location'):
>>>         redirected = e
>>>
>>> if(redirected != False):
>>>     print redirected[1]
'http://ubuntu.icafebusiness.com/images/ubuntugui2.jpg'
```

Comment: My python interpreter says "ImportError: No module named parse".Your method failed at Step 1.Any Idea?

Comment: Found it,You are using python 3 while I'm still using python 2.7 :)

Comment: One more doubt,suppose 'http://ubuntu.icafebusiness.com/images/ubuntugui2.jpg' is the url and I shortened it using google url shortner so it now becomes 'http://goo.gl/IwruD'.Now on this shortened url your method is not working,it says "ResponseNotReady".What say?

Answer (score 4):

Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) and [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to verify that it's actually a valid image:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> r = requests.get('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png')
>>> im = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
>>> im
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=238x1073 at 0x2845EA8>
```

Comment: What would happen if the image was not there? would your code crash or would you have to check some attributes of im? Can you update your code to a function returning a boolean?

Comment: Yes apart from the HTTP status code, Image.open should throw some kind of error I am thinking? PIL is not very helpful in this... I was also looking at http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.verify but can't figure out what to use.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to check this by using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo3w.png'
>>> try:
...   f = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url))
...   imageFound = True
... except:
...   imageFound = False
...
>>> imageFound
True
```